# ECSlidingViewController and Storyboards Swipe Gesture Recognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, gestures

I have implemented [ECSlidingViewController's](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController) left and right panning gesture to present child view controllers in two layers (this works fine).

I have then used storyboards to implement an *Up Swipe* and *Down Swipe* gesture between two views, but it is not working. I assume this is because ECSlidingViewController uses a global pan gesture recognizer which is overwriting storyboards drag-and-drop gestures.

Can anyone advise how I can keep ECSlidingViewController while still having my own up and down gestures? Thank you